# Are conditional expectation values the same if expectation values are the same?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and ${\bf z} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ denote two real-valued and bounded random variables.

Assume that the following expectation values are the same for all moments of $\bf x$ (for all possible ${\bf k}$): $E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{k_i}\right] = E\left[f_{\bf k}({\bf x} ,{\bf z})\right]$, where ${\bf k}=(k_1,...,k_n)$ and $k_i\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Here, $f_{\bf k}$ denote real valued scalar functions. In general, $f_{\bf k}({\bf x},{\bf z})\neq \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{k_i}$.

Then, can we conclude $E\left.\left[\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{k_i}\right|{\bf z}\right] = E\left.\left[f_{\bf k}({\bf x},{\bf z})\right|{\bf z}\right]$?

I understand that the conditional expectations have to exist because all $E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{k_i}\right]$ exist because $\bf x$ is bounded. Also, all mixed moments exist and uniquely defined the probability distribution of $\bf x$. But can the equality in the assumption transfer to the conditional expectation values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No we cannot. The following counter example disproves it.

Let $X$ and $Z$ be i.i.d. $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued bounded random vectors. Define $f_{\bf k}(X,Z) = \prod_{i=1}^n Z^{k_i}$, then by the assumption $X\sim Z$ we get
$$\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{k_i}] = \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n Z^{k_i}]=\mathbb{E}[f_{\bf k}(X,Z)]$$
although usually $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{k_i}\neq \prod_{i=1}^n Z^{k_i}$. By independence we have that
$$ \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{k_i} \: | \: Z] = \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{k_i}]$$
and by measurability we have that
$$\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n Z_i^{k_i} \: | \: Z] = \prod_{i=1}^n Z_i^{k_i}$$
and equality between the two conditional expectations would imply that $\prod_{i=1}^n Z_i^{k_i}=\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n Z_i^{k_i}]$ almost surely, which is usually not the case except for trivial/degenerate cases.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful!

Comment: No problem. I guess the lesson to be learned is that moments only carry information about the distribution and not on the dependency of other variables.

Comment: Does this mean that the statement could be true for $$E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{k_i}\right] = E\left[f_{\bf k}({\bf x})\right] \implies E\left.\left[\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{k_i}\right|{\bf z}\right] = E\left.\left[f_{\bf k}({\bf x})\right|{\bf z}\right]$$? Is this trivial or should I post another question?

Comment: This implication would not hold either: Here is a simple counter example: Consider $X=(X_1,X_2)$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d., then for all $(k_1,k_2)$
$$\mathbb{E} [X_1^{k_1}X_2^{k_2}] = \mathbb{E}[X_1^{k_2}X_2^{k_1}]$$
but if we now introduce $Z$ as $Z=X_1$, then
$$\mathbb{E} [X_1^{k_1}X_2^{k_2} \: | \: Z] = X_1^{k_1}\mathbb{E}[X_2^{k_2}]$$
while
$$\mathbb{E} [X_1^{k_2}X_2^{k_1} \: | \: Z] = X_1^{k_2}\mathbb{E}[X_2^{k_1}]$$
which is usually not the same if $k_1 \neq k_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.